# Programmatically build a WCF Binding in Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, wcf

I have a Binding that is configured as such in my .clientconfig file.

```
<customBinding>
  <binding name="CustomBinding_MyService">
    <binaryMessageEncoding />
    <httpTransport maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" />
  </binding>
</customBinding>
```

I need to build this same binding programmatically (its a long story, I just do). My question is, how do I do this in C#? Currently, I have

```
CustomBinding binding = new CustomBinding();
```

However, I'm not sure where to go from there. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

It'll look something like this:

```
var customBinding = new CustomBinding(
   new BinaryMessageEncodingBindingElement(),
   new HttpTransportBindingElement() 
       { 
          MaxReceivedMessageSize = 2147483647, 
          MaxBufferSize = 2147483647 
       } 
   );
var endpoint = new EndpointAddress("http://www.myservice.com/myservice.svc");
var myServiceClient = new MyServiceClient(customBinding, endpoint);
myServiceClient.SayHelloAsync();  // Or whatever
```

Answer (score -1):

hopefully this helps: [Runtime data binding](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/dhananjaycoder/Runtimedatabinding04202009041801AM/Runtimedatabinding.aspx)

Comment: Don't know who, but I'll guess the why is that this question is about WCF binding and your link was about data binding.

Comment: no both question and link are about Silverlight data binding.

Comment: Actually, Mike is right. The question is about WCF binding and the article is about data binding.